# Results fetched from AWS Athena have different values in timestamp column

Tags: amazon-web-services, timestamp

Data stored in S3 as *2021-06-01 12:00:00* is displayed as *2021-06-01 03:00:00* when queried with Athena.
The column type is String.
Please help me. Thank you :)

Comment: What is the format of the column -- is it `timestamp` or `varchar`? How are you querying Amazon Athena (eg are you using the console, or your own SQL client)? What timezone are you in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time change is most likely due to the SQL client adjusting the time for your timezone.

You can test this with:

```sql
SELECT
  the_field,
  CAST(the_field AS VARCHAR)
FROM table
```

The second column will convert the timestamp into a string *before* it reaches your SQL client, so no timezone conversion will be applied. If the two columns are different, it is an indication that the time shift is being caused **outside of Amazon Athena**, inside your SQL client.

Comment: The location is in Korea time zone. I found that RDS snapshots are converted to UTC when they are created. Thanks for your help!